# Finding the tangent line to $y= 7 \sin( \pi x+y)$ at the point $(-1,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

> Find the lines that are tangent and normal to the curve at the given point
>   $$y= 7 \sin( \pi x+y),  \qquad (-1,0)$$
>   The line tangent to the curve $y= 7 \sin (\pi x+y)$ at $(-1,0)$ is $y=\ ?$

How would I solve this?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the tangent line, and its relationship with the derivative at the point?

Comment: Note that the constant $\pi$ is *not* written as "pie" but as "pi."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use *Implicit Differentiation*. We get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=7\left(\pi+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\cos(\pi x+y).$$

**Added:** Now we could solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and substitute. I prefer to substitute and then solve. So let $m$ be the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(-1,0)$. Substituting, we obtain
$$m=7(\pi +m)(-1).$$
Solve for $m$. We get $m=-\frac{7\pi}{8}$.

This $m$ is the slope of our tangent line. Now I expect you can find the equation of the line that passes through $(-1,0)$ and has slope $-\frac{7\pi}{8}$.

For the equation of the normal, note that the slope of the normal is $\frac{8}{7\pi}$.

Comment: that seems pretty different from where i ended up halfway...

Comment: i got dy/dx= 7(pie) cos( (pie)x + y) + 3 cos( (pie)x+y) dy/dx

Comment: Well, continue. Set $y=0$, $x=1$, and use the fact that $\cos(-\pi)=-1$. So at $(-1,0)$ the derivative (slope) $m$ satisfies $m=7(\pi +m)(-1)$. Solve for $m$.

Comment: after that i don't know what to do. in the examples it says, collect the terms with dy/dx on one side of the equation , and then solve for dy/dx. This is where i get super confused. Then it says evaluate the derivative at the point (-1,0) to find the slope of the tangent. Then I'm supposed to substitute the values of the slope and the given point to find the y-intercept. This is so hard :'(

Comment: I will add some more to the post.

Comment: ok, i think i know what to do now. gonna find y-intercept. ok, put it in point slope formula it is

Comment: y=8/7pi + 8/7pi. ty so much for the help.

Comment: darn i was wrong…….noooooooooooooo

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating implicitly:
$$y'=7\cos (\pi x+y)(\pi +y')\Rightarrow y'=7\pi \cos(\pi x+y)+7\cos (\pi x+y)y' $$
$$\Rightarrow y'=\frac{7\pi \cos (\pi x+y)}{1-7\cos (\pi x+y)} .$$

The slope of the tangent line at $P(-1,0)$ is
$$m=y'(-1,0)=\frac{7\pi \cos (-\pi)}{1-7\cos (-\pi)}=-\frac{7\pi}{8}. $$

Then the tangent line to the curve given in $P=(x_p,y_p)=(-1,0)$ is
$$y-y_p =m(x-x_p),$$
i.e.,
$$y-0=-\frac{7\pi}{8} (x+1)\Rightarrow y=\frac{7\pi}{8}x+ \frac{7\pi}{8},$$

and how the slope of the normal line is
$$m_n=-\frac{1}{m}=\frac{8}{7\pi} $$

follows that the normal curve in $P$ is

$$y-y_p=m_n(x-x_p)\Rightarrow y=\frac{8}{7\pi}(x+1). $$